# gdb - generate-core-file for remote target?

Tags: arm, gdb, cortex-m, codesourcery

I'm debugging with the Codesourcery version of gdb for ARM (i.e. arm-none-eabi-gdb) and attempting to generate a corefile for later inspection.  OpenOCD is my GDB target.   All gdb tells me when I run 'gcore' or 'generate-core-file' is "Can't create corefile".   Any suggestions?  In general is it possible to do a core dump with a remote target?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible yet, but there is some promising discussion on the GDB mailing list
[here](http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2011-11/msg00616.html) and [here](http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2011-12/msg00012.html).  As an alternative maybe you could try the following?

```
dump memory filename.bin start_addr end_addr
restore filename.bin binary start_addr
```

where you fill in start_addr and end_addr appropriately.  You'd have to save registers by hand.